# Using classes in different .ts files in jasmine

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am writting simple test in jasmine framework. I have following files stored in one folder:

- maintest.ts
- helper.ts
- Workflow1.ts
- Workflow2.ts

Workflow files have content as following (example):

```
import {element, by, browser, protractor} from "protractor";
import {Helper} from "../../helper";

export class Workflow1/2
{
    static Foo1() {

    let element1;
    let element2;

    describe('check all fields', function () {
        it('check foobar', function () {
              element1.isVisible();
        });
        it('check foobar2', function () {
              element2.isVisible();
        });
    }

    static Foo2() {
    let element3;
    let element4;

    describe('check all fields', function () {
        it('check foobar', function () {
              element4.isVisible();
        });
        it('check foobar2', function () {
              element3.isVisible();
        });
    }
}
```

And the maintest.ts is:

```
import {browser} from "protractor";
import {Helper} from "./helper";
import {Workflow1} from "./Workflow1";
import {Workflow2} from "./Workflow2";

describe ('Regression Tests', function() {
    beforeAll(function () {
        console.log('====================Start');
});

describe('Basic workflow', function () {
    Workflow1.Foo1();
    Workflow1.Foo2();
    Workflow2.Foo2();
    Workflow2.Foo2();
});
});
```

but when I run it, nothing has run correctly - I get this error:

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

but if I comment:

```
//Workflow1.Foo2();
//Workflow2.Foo2();
//Workflow2.Foo2();
```

the `Workflow1.Foo1` works perfectly fine.

Can't I use different methods from different files? It works with helper, where I have login and logout methods...

Comment: Try disabling protractor to wait for angular. Your error is due to Protractor timing out while waiting to sync with Angular.

Comment: Where? I added  `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in helper in login method and also anywhere in maintest.ts (ie. beforeAll or in Basic Workflow)

Comment: Depending on what version of protractor you are using `browser.ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated. The new command is `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`

Comment: Good to know, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this. My code was 'quite' long with different `describe`s, when I minimalized it to 2, it started working :)

EDIT: As I mentioned in comment below, each method in Workflow1 and Workflow2 files must have at least one `describe` and at least one `it` inside - having only `describe` without `it` throws error

Comment: I don't think that is actually a solution. There is no co-relation of how many describe's a test can have. I have tests with 15+ describes and that runs perfectly fine. The error message that was thrown has been mentioned a lot of times and clarified by Protractor team to be something that is related to the Protractor script not being in sync with Angular

Comment: @demouser123 You are right, but later when I found this issue again, I found out that all methods used in maintest.ts (Worklow1 and Workflow2 in this case) must have at least one `describe` with at least one `it` - using only describe throws error about syncing with Angular